# Trying to filter of data based upon child's child model set Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Trying to create a function based where the executive get's options based upon the pincodes. Tried this method but it's not working out can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance...
(Don't judge the code because this a early stage development and I'm a beginner developer so sorry if the code isn't proper to read)

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
ADDCHKS_ID=models.CharField(max_length=16)
is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_excutive=models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ExcutiveRegistration(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
'''Personal Details'''
First_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
DOB = models.DateField(max_length=100)
Fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
Alt_Contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
# Profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")
'''Current Addresss'''
Pin_code_c = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
State_c = models.CharField(max_length=50)
District_c = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Taluk_c = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Location_c = models.CharField(max_length=100)
House_no_c = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
Street_c = models.CharField(max_length=100)
'''Permanent Address'''
Pin_code_p = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, null=True)
State_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
District_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Taluk_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
Location_p = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
House_no_p = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, null=True)
Street_p = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
'''Reference'''
Family_reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Family_reference_conatact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
Neighbour_reference_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Neighbour_reference_contact = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, null=True)
'''Document Proof'''
ID_Proof_Document_Type=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                        choices=ID_CHOICES,
                                        default="Voter",
                                        null=True)

class ExcutiveRegistrationPincode(models.Model):
ExcutiveRegistration=models.ForeignKey(ExcutiveRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Covering_Pincode=models.IntegerField(max_length=6)

class Customer(models.Model):
# user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
Verification=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                              choices=Verification_Method,
                              default=None,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True)
Client_ID=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
Client_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
Applicant_Name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
DOB=models.DateField()
Father_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,  null=True,blank=True)
Pincode=models.IntegerField(max_length=6, null=True,blank=True)
Present_address=models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)
Permanent_address=models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True,blank=True)
Contact_number=models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True,blank=True)
Alt_Contact_number=models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True,blank=True)
Selfie_with_residence=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,blank=True)
Surrounding_left=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,blank=True)
Surrounding_right=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,)
Landmark=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,blank=True)
NID_proof=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            choices=ID_CHOICES,
                            default=None,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True)
NID_proof_Image=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,blank=True)
NID_proof_Image_2=models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/Client_verification")
Candidate_Signature=models.ImageField(upload_to="images/Client_verification", null=True,blank=True)
Ref_no=models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True,blank=True)
BGV_Intiation_date=models.DateField(null=True)
Excutive_worked=models.ForeignKey(ExcutiveRegistration,models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='Excutive_worked',blank=True)
Excutive_Reworked=models.ForeignKey(ExcutiveRegistration,models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='Excutive_Reworked',blank=True)
Date_of_work_compeleted=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
Days_of_work_postponed=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
Status=models.CharField(max_length=50,
                        choices=Status__,
                        default='null',
                        null=True,
                        blank=True)
Assign=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Client_ID + self.Client_name
```

views.py

```
class excutive_home_page(View):
@login_required(login_url='login')
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user=request.user
    str_current_user=str(current_user.id)
    if current_user:
        get_excutive=ExcutiveRegistration.objects.filter(pk=str_current_user)
        str_get_excutive=str(get_excutive)
        get_excutive_pincode=ExcutiveRegistrationPincode.objects.filter(pk=str_get_excutive)
        str_get_excutive_pincode=str(get_excutive_pincode)
        customers = Customer.objects.filter(Pincodes=str_get_excutive_pincode)
        context = {
        "customers":customers,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'excutive\excutive_home_page.html', context)
   
    return HttpResponse(self.request, "try someother way")
```

excutive_home_page.html

```
hi {{request.user}}
    
  {% for customer in customers  %}
  {{customer}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the `Covering_Pincode` from the `ExcutiveRegistrationPincode`s, not use `str(…)`. But by making use of `IntegerField`s over just `ForeignKey`s, you make it harder to query, and you can not use the Django ORM effectively.

You can also simplify work by making use of a [**`TemplateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class ExcutiveHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'excutive/excutive_home_page.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        pincodes = [
            e.Covering_Pincode
            for e in ExcutiveRegistrationPincode.objects.filter(
                ExcutiveRegistration__user=self.request.user
            ).only('Covering_Pincode')
        ]
        context['customers'] = Customer.objects.filter(Pincodes__in=pincodes)
        return context
```

or even better with a simple [**`ListView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView


class ExcutiveHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    template_name = 'excutive/excutive_home_page.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pincodes = [
            e.Covering_Pincode
            for e in ExcutiveRegistrationPincode.objects.filter(
                ExcutiveRegistration__user=self.request.user
            ).only('Covering_Pincode')
        ]
        return Customer.objects.filter(Pincodes__in=pincodes)
```